# XPath query string to search text only on direct children of root element?

Tags: xml, xpath

I've just picked up XPath, and was trying to get a query work for me, but somehow it's not picking up the elements I want.

XML Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:data xmlns:d="defiant-namespace" d:constr="Array" d:mi="8">
  <d:item d:mi="2">
    <name d:constr="String" d:mi="1">Asian Winged Bean</name>
  </d:item>
  <d:item d:mi="7">
    <image d:mi="5">
      <name d:constr="String" d:mi="3">wbss-1a20ed37-e498-47ad-b97d-c36c4d653b66-mps4YI4gNB</name>
      <url d:constr="String" d:mi="4">http://dropbox.com/7f3f1192-191e-41a6-8bcd-47ab1d30af3b/wbss-1a20ed37-e498-47ad-b97d-c36c4d653b66-mps4YI4gNB</url>
    </image>
    <name d:constr="String" d:mi="6">Akha Striped Bean</name>
  </d:item>
</d:data>
```

My query is

```
//*[contains(name,"w")]
```

which picks up the first `<item>`, but it also picks up `<image>` element which I don't want it to. Is there a way to search for text only on top level elements and not their children?

Comment: I solved it myself by using this query

    //*[contains(name[1],"w")]

Comment: If that solved it, your problem isn't what you claim it to be. You specified "top level elements and not their children", but `//*[contains(name[1],"w")]` enforces no such restriction.

Comment: Hi Charles, as I said, I am new to XPath, and may be didn't phrase my question according to terminology of XPath, I did provide sample and the result I was looking for. Hope this helps a lot of experts understand this limitation one may have while asking Q's. Thanks :)

Comment: The point of accurate phrasing is to ensure that people who need it -- people with genuinely *the same problem* -- can find your question and its answers. `//*[contains(name[1], "w")]` isn't likely to be helpful to anyone but you, since what it constrains isn't distance from the root element (the subject the question title advertises this question and its answers as addressing). In this kind of case, prods about terminology should be read as requests to edit the question to make it more clear as an aid to other people seeking answers on the same topic.

Comment: Obviously, a question topic that requires a bunch of expert-only domain knowledge isn't helpful to other folks either -- the goal is to find a middle ground that serves both accuracy and accessibility.

Comment: BTW, your examples use a lower-case `w` in the query, but the name text only contains an upper-case `W`; without this corrected, testing any answer would be rather a trick.

Comment: Thanks, for your help & insightful reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an answer that's technically correct, but not (right now) useful. To make it *useful*, it would change in a manner akin to the following:

```
/*/*[contains(name,"W")]
```

Replacing `//*` with `/*/*` means that we're only traversing one level past the root of the document (that being the canonical "top level").

---

By the way -- if you know your types, you should consider avoiding `/*`; using this construct prevents indexes on element type from being used, thus preventing some common engine optimizations (when operating against indexed documents) from being used to speed your query.

Assuming you pass in some local equivalent to `{d: "defiant-namespace"}` as the namespace map to your XPath engine (an operation we can't tell you how to do without knowing your programming language, XPath library, &c), you're much better off with the following from a performance perspective:

```
/d:data/d:item[contains(name, "W")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
//*[contains(name,"w")]
```

to this

```
/*[contains(name,"w")]
```

"//" recursively searches the xml tree,
"/" only looks at the root node

Comment: I don't know if you tested it, but it says no match

Comment: @nirvana74v, this successfully implements what you *claim* to want -- it searches the top-level element only (singular, because by its nature, an XML document can have only one top-level element). None of your `item`s are top-level elements, though -- only the `data` element in your sample is top-level.